# Trying to do The Guardian newspaper for practise. My link called "here" isn't working. I've tried various debugging and can't work it out

Tags: html, css

Sorry I'm not sure how to present it to everyone.   I'm being asked for more detail, but not sure what detail is needed. The link within the div/class "here" won't work. I'm impersonating The Guardian newspaper layout for practise. Sorry if it is tedious for anyone who is experienced.

I've tried debugging with no success and changed links etc

```css
body {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.header {
  background: linear-gradient(midnightblue, blue);
  color: white;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 11;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 4em;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px midnightblue;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.latest {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.latest:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Aberdeen {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Aberdeen:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Celtic {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Celtic:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Dundee {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Dundee:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Hibs {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Hibs:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Hearts {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Hearts:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Rangers {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 7;
  grid-column-end: 8;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Rangers:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.sj {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 8;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.sj:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.Motherwell {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 9;
  grid-column-end: 10;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.Motherwell:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.RossCounty {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 10;
  grid-column-end: 11;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: white;
}

.RossCounty:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.mainstory {
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

img {
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 10;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 1em;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid white;
}

span {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.here {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 11;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rightimg {
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 11;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.hearts {
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  grid-row-start: 8;
  grid-row-end: 11;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  padding: 1em;
}

.bb {
  grid-row-start: 8;
  grid-row-end: 11;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}

.sevco {
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  grid-row-start: 8;
  grid-row-end: 11;
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.right {
  background-color: (222, 222, 222);
}

.footer {
  background-color: (222, 222, 222);
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>The Daily Truth</title>
<div class="header">
  The Daily Truth
</div>

<div class="latest">
  <a href="http://www.scotsman.com/" target="_blank">Latest</a></div>
<div class="Aberdeen">Aberdeen</div>
<div class="Celtic">Celtic</div>
<div class="Dundee">Dundee</div>
<div class="Hibs">Hibs</div>
<div class="Hearts">Hearts</div>
<div class="Rangers">Rangers</div>
<div class="sj">St J</div>
<div class="Motherwell">Motherwell</div>
<div class="RossCounty">Ross County</div>

<div class="mainstory">
  <h1>Old Firm losing the plot</h1>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. 
     Praesent Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti 
    </span>

</div>
<div class="rightimg">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHcLnfh72ChMIKiJZkT_D9Oh5islspJpRB69ypRP4ktEFCiY6P">
</div>

<div class="here">
  <a href="http://www.scotsman.com/"></a>
</div>

<div class="hearts">
  <h1>Heart of Gold</h1>
  <h4>Levein gives away money</h4>
  Hearts Director of football Craig levein today made the dreams come true for 100 Hearts fans when he gave away £1000 to each supporter, totalling a million pound donation.
</div>

<div class="bb">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqSicfQjgwI4istGd3dRTSVAAO-SIUk49YfMtgfCrwtnCZqwPJCg">
</div>

<div class="sevco">
  <h1>Rangers go bust</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
  Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosq.

</div>
```

Comment: There is no content in `here`

Comment: Also if you are loading this into JSFiddle or look at the snippet I made for you, the link will be blocked since it is http and redirects https to http too

Comment: If I press 'run code snippet' and then full screen, I see it rendered. I see content in the 'here' class, (well, the positioning in css, and a link in html) but link isn't working. Am i being an idiot?

Comment: `<div class="here">
  <a href="http://www.scotsman.com/"></a>
</div>` has a link that has nothing to click. What are you referring to? Also here at SO you cannot click the link even if there was text in it since it is http in an https environment (see the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have empty div with height 0, just write something there or put, in debugger you will see that height is 0, that is your problem!

```
 <div class="here">
  <a href="http://www.scotsman.com/">MY LINK</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a link which is transparent across the column 1 to 11, row 4 to 8. I thought the grid would provide the height automatically.

Comment: Is a link only, within a div allowed?

Comment: Will have to read about the http problem highlighted also. maybe I'm a bit too green to engage on this site

Comment: also, i don't want to write anything for the link. i want to read the story and click anywhere on it to link to another page

Comment: It's allowed but if you haven`t content set the height self, also you can wrap div with your link

Comment: set height to div and wrap this div with a tag: